# Laravel Eloquent Query Using WHERE AND WHERE

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to I write this `WHERE (a = 1) AND (a != 1 AND c=1)` query in Laravel?

I supposed to use raw SQL.

Comment: Check official Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: Your query makes no sense. Looks like you need to use `OR`.

Comment: Yes, i got confused and actually needed OR.

This is what I actually needed: Model::where('a', 1)->orWhere([['a', '!=', 1], ['b', 1]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague -- the more detail about what you tried the better the answers we can provide.  Actual examples of code you tried are also extremely helpful!

But I think you may be looking for constraint groups.   These let you combine sets of clauses and group their logic together.   [Laravel queries and parameter grouping docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping)

```
$result = Model::where('a', 1)
        ->Where(function($query){
            $query->where('a', '!=', 1);
            $query->where('c', '=', 1);
        })
        ->get();
```

Also, I'm assuming this is just an example but you probably want to change your logic as well ... `Where A = 1 AND A != 1` isn't going to return any results.